# Adding Additional Extensions Directly to X.509

Tags: openssl, x509, csr

Is it possible for the CA to intervene and add extensions to an X.509 that aren't in the CSR? For example, a company runs an internal CA, and it augments certificates with additional extensions (required for operation, therefore critical). It's a lot smoother to do this directly than expect the client to add them to the CSR themselves. The latter would probably require a tool that presents a form and then injects the extensions, rather than being able to allow the client to just invoke OpenSSL from the command-line.

This is being posted to SO because I'm an engineer doing security-related work, and am seeking the insights of those doing similar work.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, CAs construct the certificate using some information of the CSR rather than just sign the CSR. CAs add extensions *always* -- at least KeyUsage and ExtKeyUsage are set by the CA, then CRL and OCSP responder locations are also specified via extensions and are set by the CA. There can be more extensions set as well.

Comment: Fields like AKI and EKU are expected (as are some policy extensions). However, adding a deprecated field like a Common Name is not expected.

Comment: @jww the question was not about "expected", but about those that are not in the CSR.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the CA to intervene and add extensions to an X.509 that aren't in the CSR

Yes. For example, [Startcom](https://cert.startcom.org/) will add a Description, add an Email Address, and add a Common Name. So the subject's DN displayed will be similar to:

```
$ openssl x509 -in www-example-com.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 903612
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=IL, O=StartCom Ltd., OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 30 08:54:48 2014 GMT
            Not After : Jan 31 12:51:02 2015 GMT
        Subject: description=v91xHxCGaTrqOAm, C=US, CN=www.example.com/emailAddress=webmaster@example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
    ...
```

In my case, I did not specify a Description or Common Name (the Common Name is deprecated, and should not be used). I only specified two DNS Subject Alt Names (and other subject info).

A CA will also likely drop some fields, and modify or overwrite fields that you have already supplied.

A CSR is a lot like a wikipedia contribution. Don't submit it if you don't want it mercilessly edited.

---

> This is being posted to SO because I'm an engineer doing security-related work...

Its still probably off-topic :o